# "not a git command" configuring a bash script as a git alias

Tags: bash, git, alias

I want to set a specific alias in `.gitconfig` to a bash script like this:

```
[alias]
    example = "~/git-scripts/example-script.sh"
```

instead of:

```
[alias]
    example = "!f() { arg1=$1; echo $arg1; }; f"
```

So, the echo script above would be in this file `~/git-scripts/example-script.sh`

When i'm trying to execute a alias like this, i got this error:

`expansion of alias 'example' failed; ~/git-scripts/example-script.sh is not a git command`

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you try it already? What problem did you have? (If don't have any reason to believe that it doesn't work, why ask here?)

Comment: Yes, sorry, i'll edit the question. I got this error: `expansion of alias 'example' failed; '~/git-scripts/example-script.sh' is not a git command`

Comment: Ahh. Put a `!` in front. In the sample git alias you showed, the `!` isn't a part of the shell command but an instruction to git to treat everything else as a shell command. So, `example = "!~/git-scripts/example-script.sh"`

Comment: Anyhow, now that you're showing an error, I've voted to re-open. If the above comment does fix the problem, it can be added as an answer if that reopen succeeds. (If I don't see the reopen vote succeed and add an answer on my end, feel free to add that answer yourself).

Comment: Thx! I could make it work with this command in the alias: `"! bash ~/git-scripts/example-script.sh"`. if the question is reopened, I will post the answer. I don't know if it's the best option, but it worked

Comment: Hmm. If the script has a correct execute bit and shebang, you shouldn't need `bash` to be part of the command. Check that `chmod +x ~/git-scripts/example-script.sh` has been run, and that it starts with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or another bash shebang. And as an aside, consider not using file extensions on scripts; putting a `.sh` extension on a *bash* script implies to readers they can use it with `/bin/sh`. Anyhow, executable scripts define commands, and you don't run `ls.elf`.

Comment: This is the script:
`#!/bin/bash echo hello world`

Comment: Assuming newlines where they should be, that part's fine. How about file `+x` file permissions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210315/discussion-between-joao-albuquerque-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Charles Duffy said in the comments area, i could make it work like this:

```
[alias]
    example = "! ~/git-scripts/example-script"
```

Just add `!` before the script path

Be careful with:

1. Permissions: If you are in Linux, just add execution permissions like this:

   > `$ chmod +x YOUR_SCRIPT_PATH`
2. Notice that you don't need the extension (`.sh`) at the script file. You can read more about this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503127/should-i-save-my-scripts-with-the-sh-extension)